# Javascript or jquery code for screen orientation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need either Javascript or Jquery to detect screen orientation and then load different HTML and css for each orientation.

This is some of what I think is good code that I put together from different examples, but I don't know the code needed to finish it.

```
    $(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
    if(window.orientation == 0) // Portrait
    {
    jquery code here to load some external HTML AND CSS
    }
    else // Landscape
    {
    jquery code here to load some external HTML AND CSS
    }
    });
```

Does this look right and what does the code I need look like to complete this? Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Careful, [window.orientation is depricated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientation)

Comment: Check [jQuery.mobile orientationchange event](https://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/)

Comment: The  jQuery.mobile orientationchange event does only show the mode "landscape" or "portrait". Like some others here I'm looking for the angle (0, 90, ...) that was supported by the deprecated window.orientation and there seems to be no solution (or I can't find it).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of detecting orientation with JS and then repainting the display for that, why not just use CSS media queries/ responsive design for your layout?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible with jQuery Mobile

```
$(document).on("pagecreate",function(event){
  $(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
    if(window.orientation == 0)// Portrait
    {
      //....................
    }
    else
    {
      //...............
    }
  });                   
});
```

or simple, you must compare with $(window).width()

Comment: This, (whatever) code used, is going to display one type HTML footer for desktop and landscape mobile and another for mobile portrait. That's why I've taken this approach. Knowing that, do the code examples given still apply?

Comment: I only need to target mobile 0 and -90.

Answer (score 0):

Write below JS code

```
screen.addEventListener("orientationchange", function () {
      console.log("The orientation of the screen is: " + screen.orientation);
    });
```

It listen screen orientation

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right direction, but your code didn't manages all the cases (upside down ipad, for example)

Check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/shnn-snippets/2359199) with the [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) function as event handler.

P.S. use mediaqueries when is possible.